# Posting HTML in contentEditable DIV with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

Can I post the contents of a contentEditable DIV directly?  The only thing I can think of doing is copying the innerHtml into a hidden input element, but I'm sure there must be a more direct way.

**View:**

```html
<div name="typer" id="typer" onclick="eraseFirst();this.contentEditable='true';">
    Text here that the user typed, with html elements.  How is this posted?
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BlogPage(BlogsPosts blogsposts)
{
    // Is this a good start?
    return View(blogsposts);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to parse the text and either populate a hidden field that is part of your viewmodel before submitting the form or send the request via ajax.

Comment: I started doing that in the meantime.  I couldn't think of any other way either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, get the attributes from your div like this and send to controller:

```
var cod = $("#typer").attr("name")
```

Comment: This is placed in JavaScript?  How is it sent to the controller?